# Querying and filtering unique documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I've added a bunch of our pet food data into a ElasticSearch index, the data looks something like this:

```
{
  "title": "Pedigree Absolute Max, 700g Adult",
  "price": 7828,
  "supplier": "Madison Distributions",
  "supplierid": 241,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-23"
},    
{
  "title": "Pedigree Smart Choice 1kg Adult",
  "price": 3428,
  "supplier": "Madison Distributions",
  "supplierid": 241,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-23"
}
{
  "title": "Canagan Adult 1kg Refresh",
  "price": 3528,
  "supplier": "Madison Distributions",
  "supplierid": 241,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-23"
},    
{
  "title": "Skinners 15Kg Puppy Kibble",
  "price": 9228,
  "supplier": "Madison Distributions",
  "supplierid": 241,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-23"
},   
{
  "title": "Pedigree Absolute Max, 700 grams Adult Size",
  "price": 7628,
  "supplier": "Bay Pet",
  "supplierid": 313,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-23"
},  
{
  "title": "Skinners 25Kg Puppy Kibble",
  "price": 10228,
  "supplier": "Bay Pet",
  "supplierid": 313,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-23"
},
{
  "title": "Pedigree Absolute Max, 700g Adult",
  "price": 7428,
  "supplier": "Madison Distributions",
  "supplierid": 241,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-22"
},    
{
  "title": "Pedigree Absolute Max, 700 grams Adult Size",
  "price": 7528,
  "supplier": "Bay Pet",
  "supplierid": 313,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-22"
},
{
  "title": "Skinners 25Kg Puppy Kibble",
  "price": 107228,
  "supplier": "Bay Pet",
  "supplierid": 313,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-21"
},  
{
  "title": "Pedigree Absolute Max, 700g Adult",
  "price": 7228,
  "supplier": "Madison Distributions",
  "supplierid": 241,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-21"
},    
{
  "title": "Pedigree Absolute Max, 700 grams Adult Size",
  "price": 7328,
  "supplier": "Bay Pet",
  "supplierid": 313,
  "lastupdated": "2016-04-21"
}
```

Each day we index those suppliers and get their latest prices (above is a really small sample!). I'm trying to come up with a query to find the latest prices from each supplier.

I've got this which seems to work fine for now:

```
GET products/pets/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
      "query": {
        "match": { "title": "Pedigree" }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "souces": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "supplierid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": 
            [
              "title",
              "supplier",
              "lastupdated",
              "price"
            ],
            "sort": {
              "lastupdated": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the mapping I selected:

```
{
  "products": {
    "mappings": {
      "pets": {
        "properties": {
          "lastupdated": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "query": {
            "properties": {
              "match": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "supplier": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "supplierid": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing this right? Is there something I'm overlooking? The indexes are going to be broken into monthly. We monitor around 10 thousand or so products each day from our suppliers. I have not done any text cleanup yet (still prototyping!) so some will have the same product with maybe extra text at the end.

I'm unable to find "Pedigree Smart" if I change the above title match to be this:

```
"query": {
        "match": { "title": "Pedigree Smart" }
}
```

But that may be because I need to use a bool and expand each keyword to be a must->match I guess?

Answer (score 1):

In your mapping file mark **title** field as not analyzed. Basically elasticsearch will analyze the field and tokenize it on space between the **pedigree** and **smart**, so you will not be able to search it as whole. This is one part of the problem.

change this:

```
  "title": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

to:

```
  "title": {
    "type": "string"
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, I completely missed that. In your opinion do you think this is a good way to setup the index. I guess you can consider it a price comparison engine (though we have a set number of suppliers and they always change available products).

Comment: I would not say it the best, but by saying not indexed it increases your index speed as well. If your not doing a tokenized search on this filed it is better to set this as not analyzed.

Comment: just tried that, unfortunately i don't get any results for a partial match now :( I forgot to say that _all is disabled.

Comment: Yes when you mark the field as not_analyzed partial match wont return any result unless you run partial query match. Along with not_analyzed you should run partial match on that field. To achieve this you can try partial match query. **link**(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html)

Comment: Understood. Are you able to answer how you'd design something like this instead of throwing it all into one index? I was thinking of going down the path of Products then a child object that has a listing of prices. This does mean we'd have to process all different types of titles in warehouse systems to normalise names (get rid of additional attributes in the titles). Thought if we could let the search engine match terms it would be better.